# PostgreSQL метаданные секционированных таблиц

Tags: postgresql, partition, metadata

Имеется партицированная таблица

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "EventData"
(
  "event_id" uuid NOT NULL,
  "event_time" timestamp without time zone,
  "event_data" text
) PARTITION BY RANGE ("event_time");
```

Клиент по своей (неизвестной логике) создает партиции от этой таблицы.
Необходимо из метаданных БД узнать информацию, по какому значению поля "event_time" создана та или иная партиция.

Comment: `pg_dump --table tablename --schema-only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сведения о границах раздела партиции хранятся в [`pg_class.relpartbound`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)

`psql`, в частности, достаёт границу раздела таким запросом:

```
SELECT inhparent::pg_catalog.regclass,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(c.relpartbound, c.oid),
  inhdetachpending
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_inherits i ON c.oid = inhrelid
WHERE c.oid = '226340';


  inhparent  |                   pg_get_expr                    | inhdetachpending 
-------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------
 measurement | FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-03-01') TO ('2006-04-01') | f
```

Аналогичным pg_get_expr пользуется и pg_dump. Да, только вот таким выражением целиком, зато универсально для любого нативного типа партицирования. Извлекать конкретный from и to для range партицирования придётся самостоятельно.